# Pulsed source in Finite Difference Time Domain simulations

Tags: electromagnetism, simulations, plasma-physics

I want to simulate a resonator cavity with a medium inside with FDTD method. The medium has a resonant frequency $\omega_R$. I want to find ratio of outgoing $P_{out}$ power to the incoming power $P_{in}$ at the frequency $\omega$:

$A(\omega)= \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$

Currently, I use a continuous wave (CW) source at a fixed frequency. I slowly ramp the amplitude of the source and wait until the the steady state. I added a small damping to the medium. But even with the damping the resonance causes numerical problems, since the amplitude becomes very large at the resonance.

**The question:**

Is possible to use a pulsed source and still be able to obtain $A(w)$? This way the amplitude, will not become too large and numerical problems will be avoided. I am worried that the steady state is not achieved when the pulse is used as a source.

**Appendix:**

The simulations are in 2D. The medium is a magnetized plasma. The geometry is shown in the figure below.
[image: A cavity filled with a plasma. The incoming power $P_in$ and outgoing power $P_out$]

Comment: "media" is the plural of "medium"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are interested in the resonator **quality factor** $Q$ (please correct me if I'm wrong), which can be roughly defined as 
$$
Q = \frac{\mbox{stored energy}}{\mbox{energy dissipated per period}}.
$$

Since you are using a pulsed source, I guess you want to use the **ring-down method** to estimate $Q$: switching-off the driving signal leads to a decay of the stored energy (due to the dissipation) and the decay time $\tau$, the $1/e$ time, is proportional to $Q$,
$$
Q = \tau\cdot\omega_R,
$$
with the resonance frequency of the system $\omega_R$.

To finally answer your question, yes, in my understanding it should definitely be possible to measure the quality factor with a pulsed source in your FDTD-code.

The numerical instability you mentioned is a separate topic, does that occur at the metallic walls? If so, how have you modelling/realized your metal walls?